# What is the maximum allowed SQL instances with Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

How many SQL and Compute instances are allowed for Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every project has a resource limit, so it depends on your project. Check [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas) for compute engine for example.

You can check the quotas for your project using the [CE quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) and [SQL quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/quotas) pages. (Note that these links are missing the "project=myproject" query parameter).

You can also check your quotas using the [gcloud CLI tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/), e.g.:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject
```

Also make sure you have billing enabled and are the billing administrator for the project, or you won't be able to see the quota for your current project.

As you can read in the link above, you can always request that your quota limit be raised to sustain more instances.